Outlook is missing in office.com
In Microsoft 365 admin center > Users > Active users, the user shows having an 'Office 365 E1' license, just like many other users do. But when he logs in to office.com, he doesn't see Outlook among the other apps such OneDrive, Word, Excel, ... etc, even in 'All apps'.
I've tried unchecking the license, saving and checking it back among other things to no avail. Does someone have any idea?

They're all checked, but there isn't Outlook among them.
Screenshot

At the screen where you select a license, at the bottom, there is a section called Apps that you can open. Is it selected there as well? I've seen situations where the license is applied but not the apps.

According to the edit, it should work. You can try logging in yourself, see if you see it, maybe the user doesn't know where to look. If you don't see it either, open a support tichet with Microsoft from the admin dashboard.
